# SSL Errors - Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I am new to Azure API Management. We are trying to send a custom response to consumer in case of ssl errors.
Can you please help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients

A sample policy below

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint != "desired-thumbprint")" >
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
    </return-response>
  </when>
</choose>
```